# SQLite 1.0.65 Assembly binding error

Tags: c#, sqlite, assemblies

I am developing an outlook add in, which uses SQLite. Outlook is throwing an exception Unable to bind assembly. I enabled the fusion log and found out that "Managed Assembly" is loading fine as it is visible from  the following log

```
    *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (16/08/2012 @ 14:13:37) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
 LOG: DisplayName = System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
     (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/TargetIntegration/CiviSync/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
    LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
    LOG: Cache Base = NULL
    LOG: AppName = OUTLOOK.EXE
    Calling assembly : ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqliteNET, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE.Config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: 
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
    LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/TargetIntegration/CiviSync/System.Data.SQLite.DLL.
    LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\<CompName>\CiviSync\System.Data.SQLite.dll
    LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
    LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
    WRN: A duplicate assembly was found while copying the assembly item to the cache.
    LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\9N164N9X.7OK\DRB00MX7.CBX\2f49c891\005cc530_ea6ccd01\System.Data.SQLite.dll.
    LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

But it is throwing an exception while loading the native assembly, as per the following exception.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (16/08/2012 @ 14:13:37) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/TargetIntegration/CiviSync/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = OUTLOOK.EXE
Calling assembly : ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqliteNET, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: Start binding of native image System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139.
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\9N164N9X.7OK\DRB00MX7.CBX\2f49c891\005cc530_ea6ccd01\System.Data.SQLite.dll.
```

I have no idea, why is this happening. This is happening on one of the client machine after the release build. On my machine even after the release build it is working fine.

Not even that, even after the exception, add in works fine.

Regards
Mohit Thakral

Answer (score 1):

Generally most Sqlite issues are a result of a 32bit / 64bit dll mismatch. You'll need to pick the most appropriate Sqlite library for your platform:

- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32) - 32bit Mixed mode .NET only assembly
- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64) - 64bit Mixed mode .NET only assembly
- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono) - 32bit unmanaged dll, compatible with .NET / Mono

The .NET only versions are mixed mode assemblies with a native version of sqlite3.dll embedded whilst the Mono / .NET version contains external 32/64 bit Windows dlls. If you use this you'd need to copy the appropriate **sqlite3.dll** into your project directory and set the **Build Action** to **Copy If Newer**.

You should be able to use either Mono or Mixed Mode assembly for your platform.

Comment: Thanks for reply Demis, I am using "ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32" only. ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32.3.8.3 is the exact version I am using. 

In nuget package there is a "System.Data.SQLite.dll", This file is  in lib dir. Seems like that could have been an issues.In the details of the file it says original filename as  "SQLite3.DLL 3.6.16."